# Can I auto-detach SqlResultSetMapping Entity from EntityManager?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using a `@SqlResultSetMapping` for an `@Entity` that is purely read-only (and has no backing table in the database). I'm loading tens of thousands of these into memory, so I need to detach the entities from the EntityManager to avoid Hibernate's dirty entity checking when I do work later.

Is there a way to annotate the Entity, or the SqlResultSetMapping, so that the entities are never added to the EntityManager?

Non-persisted entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "fooMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Foo.class))
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    public Long row_id;
    public String name;
}
```

Native query:

```
String sql = "SELECT id AS row_id, friendlyName AS name FROM SomeTable"; 
Query q = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(sql, "fooMapping");
List<Foo> fooList = q.getResultList();
```

Current solution:

```
for (Foo f : fooList) {
    JPA.em().detach(f); // 100x improvement for subsequent DB work
}

// subsequent database work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid dirty checking is to indicate to hibernate that the query is fetching read-only entities. You can do this in JPA by using [query hints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setHint%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
q.setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly",true);
```

From [hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1093):

> **org.hibernate.readOnly** : Entities retrieved by this query will be loaded in a read-only mode where Hibernate will never dirty-check them or make changes persistent ( eg. new Boolean(true) ), default to false

Comment: I think this is safe enough, because it is easy for other programmers to follow by example. Profiling suggests it is as efficient as `for (Foo f : fooList) { JPA.em().detach(f); }`.